# write csv row (from within for loop) out to csv file without using python csv module

Tags: python, csv, file-io

**My goal is to avoid importing the csv module

I am working on a script that runs through an extremely large csv file and selectively writes rows to a new csv file.

I have the following two lines:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as ifile, open(sys.argv[2], mode = 'w') as ofile:
    for row in ifile:
```

and then this, a few nested-if statements down:

```
line = list(ifile)[row]
ofile.write(line)
```

I know that isn't right--I took a stab at it and was hoping someone here could shed some light on how to correctly go about this.  The essence of this question is how to reference the row that I am in so that I can write it out to the new csv file using 'ofile'.  Please let me know if any further clarifications are necessary.  Thanks!

EDIT: Full Code included in pastebin link - http://pastebin.com/a0jx85xR

Comment: Hey there! What problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: The csv file that is created is empty.  I don't know what else to try because I am used to working with the csv module but I cannot do so in this case.  I should have mentioned in the body of the question (and I will add it in momentarily) that the essence of my question is how to reference the row that I am currently in so that I can write it out to 'ofile'.

Comment: Just for context and better communication, could you explain *why* you can't use the `csv` module?

Comment: @kojiro sure.  the csv file that i am currently dealing with is a small sample of the one that my script will eventually need to deal with.  that one has 235 million lines and is 2.5 gb.  using a csv reader would read the file into memory, which would be awful (if i understand correctly).

Comment: @user1535701 ah, that's good context, because the `csv` module does not read the entire file into memory. Glad I asked.

Comment: @kojiro so you don't think that using the csv module would cause any problems in terms of memory usage/runtime when using this script on the 2.5 gb csv?

Comment: A `csv.reader` object is an iterator, like a file object is. It doesn't read the whole file in at once, unless explicitly pass it to something that consumes all its values (like `list(reader)`). If you iterate over the reader's rows instead (with `for row in reader`), it will only read one line at a time into memory.

Comment: By the way, `list(ifile)[row]` does not work for two reasons. First, `row` is the contents of the row (a string), not an integer that you could use to index a `list`. The other reason is that is that the `list` constructor will consume the whole file. That only works once of course, since you'll be at the end of the file afterwards. So, if you need to index, read the whole file into a list once, then index with integers. If you don't need to index (and from the size of the file, you surely don't want to if you don't need to), you should just use `row` as the value directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close. This is all you have to do:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as ifile, open(sys.argv[2], mode = 'w') as ofile:
    for row in ifile:

    #...
    #You've defined some_condition to be met (you will have to replace this for yourself)
    #E.g.: the number of entries in each row is greater than 5:
        if len([term for term in row.split('#') if term.strip() != '']) > 5:
            ofile.write(row)
```

UPDATE:

To answer the OP's question about splitting lines:

you split a line in Python by supplying the delimiting character. Since this is a CSV file, you split the line by the `,`. Example:

If this is a line (a string):

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

If you apply:

```
line.split(',')
```

You'll obtain *a list*:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

UPDATE 2:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ticker = sys.argv[3]
    allTypes = bool(int(sys.argv[4])) #argv[4] is a string, you have to convert it to an int, then to a bool

    with open(sys.argv[1]) as ifile, open(sys.argv[2], mode = 'w') as ofile:
        all_timestamps = [] #this is an empty list
        n_rows = 0
        for row in ifile:
            #This splits the line into constituent terms as described earlier
            #SAMPLE LINE:
            #A,1,12884902522,B,B,4900,AAIR,0.1046,28800,390,B,AARCA,
            #After applying this bit of code, the line should be split into this:
            #['A', '1', '12884902522', 'B', 'B', '4900', 'AAIR', '0.1046', '28800', '390', 'B', 'AARCA']
            #NOW, you can make comparisons against those terms. :)

            terms = [term for term in row.split(',') if term.strip() != '']
            current_timestamp = int(terms[2])

            #compare the current against the previous
            #starting from row 2: (index 1)
            if n_rows > 1:
                #Python uses circular indices, hence: -1 means the value at the last index
                #That is, the previous time_stamp. Now perform the comparison and do something if that criterion is met:
                if current_timestamp - all_timestamp[-1] >= 0:
                    pass #the pass keyword means to do nothing. You'll have to replace it with whatever code you want

            #increment n_rows every time:
            n_rows += 1

            #always append the current timestamp to all the time_stamps
            all_timestamps.append(current_timestamp)


            if (terms[6] == ticker):
                # add something to make sure chronological order hasn't been broken
                if (allTypes == 1):
                    ofile.write(row)
            #I don't know if this was a bad indent of not, but you should know
            #where this goes
            elif (terms[0] == "A" or terms[0] == "M" or terms[0] == "D"):
                print row
                ofile.write(row)
```

My original conjecture was correct. **You weren't splitting the row into the the CSV components.** Hence, when you were making comparisons on the rows, you weren't getting the correct results - thus, you weren't getting any output. This ought to work now (given slight modifications as per your objectives). :)

Comment: (presumably with something in the for loop, or different indentation)

Comment: ah! very simple.  thank you.  unfortunately, the csv file is still empty.  perhaps it is worth mentioning that the number of column entries in each row is not equal, depending on the row type.  also, a question I need clarification on: is the first entry of a row accessed by row[0] or row[1]?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1535701: that should not matter. I'm looking into it. Also, the first entry of a row is accessed by `row[0]`. But, as `line` is a string, you're only accessing the **first character of the line** and not the first entry. In order to access the first entry, you actually need to `split()` the line using the `,` as a delimiter.

Comment: @user1535701: I'm not having any problems with the above. Are you still having issues?

Comment: what exactly are you checking for in that complex if statement and why? and if each line has 5 or more entries, why can't you just check against 1?

Comment: @user1535701: that's just an example that checks to see that there are more than 5 terms in the line, and if there is, write that line to the output file. Since it's only there for illustrative purposes (as you said your code had if statements in it), you can replace it with whatever criteria/criterion that you're trying to match.

Comment: oh okay. i've got the checks in place, and adopted your more elegant ofile.write(row) solution, but the csv is still empty.  i am not doing anything with splitting--is that the problem?

Comment: @user1535701: again, that's quite peculiar as it works quite well on mine. And, the string splitting has nothing to do with the problem. Two questions: what OS are your using? And, how are your running your program? Is it something like this: `script.py ifile.csv ofile.csv`?

Comment: i'm running this script on OS X Mavericks. the files are all on my desktop, so after making Desktop the cd in terminal, the run looks like: `python ./first_try.py ./sample.csv ./1.csv AAIR 0`.  "first try" is the script name, "sample" is the ifile, "1" is the ofile, and the following two arguments are irrelevant to this issue.  If you'd like further clarification, I'd be happy to explain in greater detail what's going on.

Comment: @user1535701: Again, I've tested it, without any problems. That's quite a mystery. Out of curiosity, does the script ever complete? Or, do you stop it midway?

Comment: the script does complete, and the csv file "1" is created.

Comment: @user1535701: Okay, let's try trouble-shooting this - because it should have worked. Try outputting some of the lines: i.e. `print line`. Since you have a large file, it will output a massive amount of text. So, when running your program do this: `python ./first_try.py ./sample.csv ./1.csv AAIR 0 > output && wc -l output`. Or, you can use `head` on the captured output to see what's in it.

Comment: will `print row` work instead of `print line`? Also, I'd like to get this into a debugger similar to gdb for c++--got any recommendations?

Comment: @user1535701: `print row`. As for a debugger, use `pdb`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: i think i've found (the first part of) the issue.  i check the string argument (ex: AAIR) against row[6].  that if statement is never evaluating to true.  is there anything i need to do to that argument in the script?

Comment: @user1535701: hold on. I think you should post your full code. There's a problem with how you're checking terms against the string argument.

Comment: i'll post it in the question

Comment: @user1535701: could you also post a sample line of the input text file, please?

Comment: I don't think you should be closing ifile and ofile after the with statement. Also, you don't need to import string. One last thing, you said the number of elements in a row is variable, are you sure they all have at least 7 so the check against ticker is valid?

Comment: @savagent: correct, he shouldn't as `with` handles that for him. I was addressing that in my update, pending the forthcoming data.

Comment: And bool(sys.argv[4]) evaluates to true since sys.argv[4] is a string.

Comment: they definitely all have at least seven.  here is a sample line of the input text:
`A,1,12884902522,B,B,4900,AAIR,0.1046,28800,390,B,AARCA,`

Comment: In the code you pasted, you've still not split the fields. As jrd1 said earlier, row[6] is the seventh letter of the string row, which for the line you just pasted in the comment would be 8.

Comment: I would be careful with the if term.strip() != ' ' bit. If you do this, you might remove an empty term, which may actually be perfectly valid, but then when you check terms[6] == ticker you're actually checking the wrong field.

Comment: @jrd1 Amazing! Thank you so much for the help--i really appreciate you taking the time to go through this.  if i had the reputation, i'd upvote the shit out of what you put here.  could you provide some explanation on that line with term for term? that's the key line, i assume, and I'd like to know how to deal with this kinda stuff later.  Again, you're awesome!

Comment: @user1535701: the line: `terms = [term for term in row.split(',') if term.strip() != '']` is a list that is created using a generator (look that up). In other words, the row is first split by the commas: i.e. `row.split(',')` which generates a list of the tokens delimited by the commas - which I then clean off of whitespace using `strip()`. However, if you have a term like this: `,\n` which is empty, you have to correct for that by comparing to see if the delimited and stripped string is not empty. If it isn't, store it in the list.

Comment: @user1535701: If you found my answer to be useful, please consider it for acceptance (the checkmark on the side of my answer). :)

Comment: @jrd1 thank you for that explanation.  one last unrelated question.  there is a timestamp associated with each row of the csv.  i want to check to make sure that the timestamp is never decreasing (that is, the difference between two consecutive rows' timestamps is always >= 0).  I have implemented a timestamp variable inside of the forloop and initiated it properly.  is there a method to compare it to the previous row, for rows 2 through N?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to jrd1's answer. I rarely use the csv module, I just use the split and join methods on strings. Usually I end up with something like this (I normally just use stdin and stdout if there's only one input and output).

```
import sys as sys

for row in sys.stdin:
  fields = row.split(",") #Could be "\t" or whatever, default is whitespace

  #process fields in someway (0 based indexing)
  fields[0] = str(int(fields[0]) + 55) 
  fields[7] = new_date_format(fields[7])
  if(some_condition_is_met):
    print(",".join(fields))
```

Of course, if your csv file starts getting some funky entries with quotes and internal commas etc. then this approach won't be so much fun

Comment: Note that the return value of `split` will be a list of strings, so for `fileds[0] += 55` to work you will need a conversion to `int` first (and back to `str` afterwards, since `join` only works on strings).

Comment: @Blckknght, yes, that's true. I'll fix it up.